# Passing this as argument to members in C++

Tags: c++

I want to pass `this` as argument to member variable like this:

```
template<class T>
struct fun
{
    fun(T* pointer) : memberPointer(pointer)
    {
    }
    T* memberPointer;
};

struct gun
{
    gun() : member(this)
    {
    }
    fun<gun> member;
};
```

In Visual Studio I have next warning: `warning C4355: 'this' : used in base member initializer list`

Can you please explain why is it wrong to do this? I just store the pointer in member constructor to use it later to call some `gun` functions from `fun`.

Comment: It isn't necessarily wrong. The warning tells you you *could* be using `this` before the object is constructed. Since your `gun` class has no data, and you are not using the pointer in the `fun` constructor, it looks OK in this case.

Comment: This is a relatively stupid warning, since what you're doing is a frequent idiom.  Just add `/wd4355` to the command line.  (There's also an entry in the properties: Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Advanced -> Disable Specific Warnings.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The potential problem is that `this` points to an object that has not been fully constructed. So for example if you had this:

```
template<class T>
struct fun
{
    fun(T* pointer) : memberPointer(pointer)
    {
        memberPointer->callMethod(); //this is 2nd to execute
    }

    T* memberPointer;
};

struct gun
{
    gun() : member(this) //this is 1st to execute
    {
       ptr = new char(); // this is 4rd to execute unless earlier UB prevents execution
    }
    void callMethod()
    {
       printf("%s", ptr); //this is 3rd to execute, you get UB here
    }
   fun<gun> member;
   char* ptr;
};
```

you would run into undefined behavior because you would pass a pointer to a not fully constructed object where only a pointer to a fully constructed object should be passed. I intentionally crafted some crappy code with UB to be more convincing, in real life you won't necessarily have UB as a problem, sometimes all the objects will be in valid states so you will get some really subtle initialization order bugs.

That's not your case. Your case is fine - you don't care that the object is not yet fully constructed. However you should be careful when changing your code so that you don't get into scenario as above.

Answer (score 1):

It's only a warning. If you were to deference `this` inside the fun constructor then you would be accessing an uninitialised object. But you aren't, you are only storing the pointer, so you can ignore the warning. If you want to turn off the warning then add this at the top of your code

```
#pragma warning (disable: 4355)
```

Comment: Btw "only a warning" doesn't mean it's not a serious problem - the compiler is allowed to emit warnings (or do nothing) in many UB cases.

Comment: @sharptooth There are warnings, and there are warnings.  Some warnings do warn about potentially serious problems.  This isn't one of them.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Sure. I just want to say that "only a warning" does not mean it's not a serious problem.

Answer (score 0):

It is not completely wrong, but as you pass the pointer, your gun object might not be fully constructed yet. Hence, it might happen that you call methods in the base class that rely on the complete construction of your object.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is to achieve static polymorphism, which is best handled through the [curiously recurring template pattern (CRTP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). In your case, you're almost there:

```
template<class Base>
struct fun : public Base
{
    void foo()
    {
        // call gun function
        Base::bar();
    }
};

struct gun : public fun<gun>
{
    void bar()
    {
        /*...*/
    }
};
```

Comment: You don't know that. Maybe he wants to be able to copy `fun<gun>` around, maybe not, but there is no way to tell from the example above.

Comment: @MatthieuM. "...to use it later to call some `gun` functions from `fun`" really sounds like static polymorphism to me...